# How to recall the publish function on the server on reload in meteor

Tags: collections, meteor, publish-subscribe

On the server side I want to publish only the data that concerns the current day.

This is my code on the server  :

```
Meteor.publish('myData', function() {
  var today = new Date();
  today.setSeconds(0);
  today.setMinutes(0);
  today.setHours(0);

  var tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setSeconds(59);
  tomorrow.setMinutes(59);
  tomorrow.setHours(23);
  return MyData.find({mTime : {$gt:today.getTime(), $lt:tomorrow.getTime()}});
});
```

The problem is that it seems this code is launched only when i deploy the app on the server.
So it is only getting the day of the deployment.

How can i get my app to republish the collection on accessing the app or on reload ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to place your `subscribe` code into `Meteor.startup()` function on the client side.

e.g.

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
   Meteor.startup(function(){
       Meteor.subscribe('myData');
   });
}
```

This will re-subscribe the `myData` whenever the app is reloaded or refreshed.

Comment: But the problem is not with the subscribe, it's with the publish that is outdated. Resubscribing will fetch the data again but it's the wrong data.

Comment: *Data that concerns current day*. You mean current day of client, right? In that case you should send today's date `(new Date())` from subscribe call. That should work.

Comment: you're right that was the solution, i sent the date as a parameter in subscribe